# Creating and trigger dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I just can't figure this out... I am trying to create a list. In every li there is the same users.

I want to create a unique div id for each user so it would be possible to click and link to specific click functions...

Here is what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var columnsarray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        var userarray = [];

        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){

            userarray.push("<div id='userholder-"+j+"-"+i+"'>UserID "+j+"</div>");

            $(function(){
                $("#userholder-"+j+"-"+i+"").click(function() {
                    alert("It Works!");
                });
            });
        }

        columnsarray.push($("#thelist").append("<li><div class='info'></div>"+userarray+"</li>"));

    }

});
```

When using the j and i in my "userholder" it won't work... If I discard the j and i it works just perfect... Is it impossible to do what I am trying to do???

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/sTULJ/

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: thats a wrong way to approach any click.you can use this  instead...

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the right way.

Add a class to every div, and a data-id to get when you call the click function:

the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var columnsarray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        var userarray = [];

        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){

            userarray.push("<div id='userholder-"+j+"-"+i+"' class='press' data-id='"+j+"-"+i+"'>UserID "+j+"</div>");

        }

        columnsarray.push($("#thelist").append("<li><div class='info'></div>"+userarray+"</li>"));

    }
    $('.press').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
    })

});
```

The fidle updated: -> http://jsfiddle.net/sTULJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use live method to attache event handlers as you create the elements dynamically. There are not elemets that match the selector at the time you register the handler. try changingyou code to use live like this:

```
 $("#userholder-"+j+"-"+i+"").live("click",function(){
 alert("It Works!");
  }
 );
```

Comment: .live is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the `class` attribute and have the click event for that class like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var columnsarray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        var userarray = [];

        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){

            userarray.push("<div id='userholder-"+j+"-"+i+"' class='clickClass'>UserID "+j+"</div>");

        }

        columnsarray.push($("#thelist").append("<li><div class='info'></div>"+userarray+"</li>"));

    }

    $(".clickClass").click(function(){
         alert("It Works!");
    });

});
```

Check the js Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/KG4LD/